# Populating other columns in the dataframe based on column-names present in one column

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a dataframe with ~300 columns, having columns from 'Prod1' to 'Prod300' , just like below :

```
ID   Product Prod1 Prod2 Prod3 Prod4 Prod5 Prod6 Prod7
01     1      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
01     2      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
01     3      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
02     1      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
02     4      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
03     3      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
04     6      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

What I want is to simply populate the corresponding 'Prod' column according to the value in 'Product' column, i.e. the below df as Output -

```
ID   Product Prod1 Prod2 Prod3 Prod4 Prod5 Prod6 Prod7
01     1      1     0     0     0     0     0     0
01     2      0     1     0     0     0     0     0
01     3      0     0     1     0     0     0     0
02     1      1     0     0     0     0     0     0
02     4      0     0     0     1     0     0     0
03     3      0     0     1     0     0     0     0
04     6      0     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

The thing is, I know I have only 300 products in total, but I may not get all the values inside the 'Product' column and I want to keep the 'Prod7' column too even if it isnt present in the 'Product' column and have all values = 0.
So, I cant use pivot_table...

I have tried looping through the 'Product' column, like below :

```
for row in range ( len( df['Product'])) :
   df['Prod' + str( df['Product'][row] ) ][row] = 1
```

what I am doing above is going through the values in the 'Product' column one by one, and then populating 1 in the corresponding column and same row.

Also, since there are 300 columns from Prod1 to Prod300 I would like not to do it column by column like below :

```
df['Prod1'] = np.where(df['Product'] == 1, 1 , 0)
df['Prod2'] = np.where(df['Product'] == 2, 1 , 0)
df['Prod3'] = np.where(df['Product'] == 3, 1 , 0)
........
........
```

Now the above codes works, but I know you shouldn't use for loops since they are slow.

Maybe its because I am new to python, and its really simple but any alternative will be much appreciated. I am also concerned about the Run-time of the code so anything faster than before will be very much helpful...

Comment: I can't imagine why you would want to do this. See X, Y problem. What is it that you _actually_ want to do?

Comment: @ifly6 This looks very much like [1-hot encoding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/), perhaps for some sort of machine learning task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty columns are not necessary here.

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) for new indicator columns, add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add non exist columns by `range` and last [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df['Product'])
         .reindex(range(1, 8), axis=1, fill_value=0)
         .add_prefix('Prod'))
print (df1)
   Prod1  Prod2  Prod3  Prod4  Prod5  Prod6  Prod7
0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
1      0      1      0      0      0      0      0
2      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
3      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
4      0      0      0      1      0      0      0
5      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
6      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
```

And then is possible use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with first 2 columns of original `DataFrame`:

```
df2 = df.iloc[:, :2].join(df1)
print (df2)
   ID  Product  Prod1  Prod2  Prod3  Prod4  Prod5  Prod6  Prod7
0   1        1      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
1   1        2      0      1      0      0      0      0      0
2   1        3      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
3   2        1      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
4   2        4      0      0      0      1      0      0      0
5   3        3      0      0      1      0      0      0      0
6   4        6      0      0      0      0      0      1      0
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do :

```py
df.iloc[range(df.shape[0]),df['Product']] = 1
```

if the `ID` is a column and not an index, you'd  do :

```py
df.iloc[range(df.shape[0]),df['Product']+1] = 1
```

for example :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product':[1, 3, 2, 3,4]})
df['prod1'] = df['prod2'] = df['prod3'] = df['prod4'] = 0
df.iloc[range(df.shape[0]),df['Product']] = 1
df
>>
Product prod1   prod2   prod3   prod4
0   1   1   0   0   0
1   3   0   0   1   0
2   2   0   1   0   0
3   3   0   0   1   0
4   4   0   0   0   1
```